# glossaries - \setglossarystyle is an undefined control sequence

Tags: glossaries

I'm having an issue where I'm fully able to create a glossary with the glossaries package, but I'm unable to change the style - the command \setglossarystyle isn't recognised.

This example works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym, nopostdot, nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\newacronym{acr}{acr}{Acronym}
\makeglossaries
\begin{document}

\acrshort{acr}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

\end{document}
```

But this one fails, with an error complaining that \setglossarystyle is an undefined control sequence:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym, nopostdot, nonumberlist]{glossaries}
\newacronym{acr}{acr}{Acronym}
\makeglossaries
\begin{document}

\acrshort{acr}
\setglossarystyle{long}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

\end{document}
```

Am I missing a package or something somewhere?

Comment: Can you look in the `.log` file for `glossaries.sty` in order to show the version you're using? You should find a string such as `Package: glossaries 2014/04/04 v4.07 (NLCT)`

Comment: works fine for me - could you add `\listfiles` immediately before your `\begin{document}` and then paste the output as part of your question... sounds like an update might be in order: [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437)

Comment: `\setglossarystyle` was introduced in version v3.08a.

Comment: Yeah, I had v3.07. Updating solved the problem. Thanks! ^_^

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an issue fixed by updating the installed package version.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot I am sorry, but I would be grateful if you could tell me why `\setglossarystyle` results in an error in [this example](https://pastebin.com/XT9zJ4C3).

Comment: @Diaa I recommend you post it as a new question giving the error message and `glossaries` version.